# Flutter : When the number of textfield characters increases, the problem is that the characters are hidden at the bottom

Tags: flutter

```
                      Container( 
                        width: 350,
                        height: 40,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(228, 228, 228, 1),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 10),
                              width:235,
                              height: 30,
                              child: 
                                TextField(
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  controller:review,
                                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)
                                ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(onPressed: null , icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle, size:20, color: Colors.black ))
                          ]
                        )
                      ),
```

If there are not many characters, the ui is as follows.

[image]

When the number of characters increases, the change of the ui is as follows.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove the fixed height from that container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the fixed height from `Container`; otherwise, you can try with this [autosizetext](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) for the fixed height text box

```
Container(
            width: 350,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              color: const Color.fromRGBO(228, 228, 228, 1),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 10),
                  width: 235,
                  child: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      cursorColor: Colors.black,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle, size: 20, color: Colors.black))
              ],
            ),
          )
```

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Add minLines and maxLines to TextField like this

```
TextField(
   keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
   controller: review,
   cursorColor: Colors.black,
   // Add here
   minLines: 1,
   maxLines: 10,
   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

put maxLines:1

```
TextField(
    maxLines: 1,
 keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
   controller: review,
   cursorColor: Colors.black,
  
   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
)
```